# How to deserialize a very large JSON string

Tags: json, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm using the below API to load data into our application

[REC Registry](https://rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/api/public-register/certificate-actions)

As per the specification, it uses the date in YYYY-MM-DD format as input.
I'm trying to `Deserialize` the returned JSON string but due to the large amount of data; I'm getting the connection failure error.

Is there a better way (probably asynchronous) to do the same? I tried searching but most of the solutions involve `.NET`.

Code so far:

```
<cfhttp url="https://rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/api/public-register/certificate-actions"
        result ="RecRegistry_JSON" 
        method="GET" getasbinary="never">
    <cfhttpparam name="Date" value="#Dateformat(DateAdd("d",-3, Now()),"YYYY-MM-DD")#" type="URL">
</cfhttp>

<cfset recJSON = DeserializeJSON(RecRegistry_JSON.FileContent)>

<cfdump var="#recJSON#">
```

Edit 1 : Based on Adam Cameron's comment, the issue is with `cfdump` for not able to dump huge chunks of data. The `deserialisation` works perfectly fine with 20 MB worth of data.

Comment: Is it definitely the deserialisation, and not the dump? If it's a massive chunk of data, `<cfdump>` will choke. Have you tried Google's GSON library?

Comment: The error-prone JSON data is worth 20 MB. Not sure if that's big enough for deserialisation or cfdump. Smaller chunks of 5MB worked out just fine. I haven't tried GSON yet; will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: When you say a "connection failure" error, that sounds like the HTTP call going bad, not the deserialisation or the dump. Can you post the actual error message.

Comment: It worked for me for couple of dates, which means that the connection is fine. Also for the 20mb data, `recregistry_json.filecontent` is dumped out fine. I don't have the exact error right now as I'm on mobile but the stacktrace had `java json util` errors.

Comment: Running the above code in Railo 4.2.1.001 I get a Heap space error on the `cfhttp` call. If I change the `dateAdd()` call to go back one day, it works as expected - still a lot of data, though.

Comment: try the attribute charset="UTF-8" in the cfhttp tag and run  this on the response before deserializing. rereplacenocase( recRegistry_JSON.FileContent,"\\u([a-z0-9]{4})","Replaced Unicode","all") I had this problem before and remember it had something to do with charset data type.

Comment: @AdamCameron : Thanks, it was the `cfdump` which was causing the issue. The deserialisation worked out just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In running your code locally the issue I am having is the HTTP request timing out. To solve this issue I added a timeout parameter to the cfhttp tag as well as a cfsetting tag to the top of the page.

```
<cfsetting requestTimeout="9000">
<cfhttp 
        url="https://rec-registry.gov.au/rec-registry/app/api/public-register/certificate-actions"
        result ="RecRegistry_JSON" 
        method="GET" 
        getasbinary="never" 
        timeout="9000" 
        file="response.json"
        path="#expandPath('/')#"
>
    <cfhttpparam name="Date" value="#Dateformat(DateAdd("d",-3, Now()),"YYYY-MM-DD")#" type="URL">
</cfhttp>
```

I also split the functions of downloading the file and parsing the file so I did not have to wait on the download to test the parsing. Note the file and path settings on the cfhttp tag.

Not knowing how you intend to process the data you may be better off getting smaller chunks such as getting 1 day at a time and compiling those results after being put into a local solution.